# Date class issue : Date object is being set to something I did not set

Tags: java

I am trying to add a delay to a `TrainTimeTable`. I have made the train arrival and departures using `Date` objects. When I first print the schedule everything is showing the correct arrival and departure times.
However, after adding a 30 minute delay to all stations Edmonton and after.
Some of the arrival and departure times become incorrect.
The delay should only push arrival and departure times back but it changes the trip time between some cities.

I have made my getters and setters like so:

```java
/**
 * Accessor for arrival Date variable. Returns a copy of the arrival date.
 * @return - a copy of the arrival date
 */
public Date getArrivalDate()
{
    //return a copy of the original date
    return (Date) arrival.clone();
}


/**
 * Mutator for arrival date variable.
 * @param arrival - the date to set 
 */
public void setArrivalDate( Date arrival )
{
    //uses copy of Date passed in
    this.arrival = (Date) arrival.clone();
}
```

Here is my method for adding the delay
I use a `LinkedList` of `Station` objects to hold the schedule:

```java
public void delay(String Station, int minute) {
    //sequential search for Station
    //iterate through list for Station
    boolean delayPoint = false;

    //1 ) adjust time of day
    //add delay to arrival and departure date objects
    for (Station current : schedule) {
        //By checking for delay before checking for the delay city
        //we will see the delayPoint variable set while on
        //the loop is at the station right afer the delayed Station
        //if after the delay point 
        if (delayPoint) {
            //then add delay to arrive date
            Date arrivalDate = current.getArrivalDate();
            long arrivalTime = current.getArrivalDate().getTime();
            arrivalTime += minute * MIN_TO_MS;
            arrivalDate.setTime(arrivalTime);
            current.setArrivalDate(arrivalDate);
            //and add delay to depart date
            Date departDate = current.getDepartureDate();
            long departTime = current.getDepartureDate().getTime();
            departTime += minute * MIN_TO_MS;
            departDate.setTime(departTime);
            current.setDepartureDate(departDate);

        } //if the Station matches the point of delay  
        else if (current.getCity().equals(Station)) {
            //then set the boolean
            delayPoint = true;
            //and add delay to departure
            Date departDate = current.getDepartureDate();
            long departTime = current.getDepartureDate().getTime();
            departTime += minute * MIN_TO_MS;
            departDate.setTime(departTime);
            current.setDepartureDate(departDate);
        }

    }
    //2 ) adjust day of trip
}
```

[Here is my output after adding a delay of 30 min to Edmonton departure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMGhW.jpg)

Please and Thank you,
Ahsen Husain.

Comment: can you show us the call for `delay()` method

Comment: Clone `Date` by `this.arrival = new Date(arrival.getTime());`

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution (based on java 8 and java.time api)

Station Class

```
    public class Station {
        private long id;
        private String name;
        private Date arrivalDate;
        private Date departureDate; ....getters and setters
```

ArrayList of Stations

```
    List<Station> myStations = Arrays.asList(
            new Station(1,"City1",new Date(),new Date()),
            new Station(2,"City2",new Date(),new Date()),
            new Station(3,"City3",new Date(),new Date()),
            new Station(4,"City4",new Date(),new Date())
    );
```

The City name to find and delay time in minutes.

```
String cityName = "City2";
int minutes = 30;
```

Get the Station that is equal to CityName (At this moment I'm showing an alternative to represent the foor loop)

```
    Station current = myStations.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.getName().equals(cityName))
            .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

The current station is equal to City Name so lets add delay

```
delay(current,minutes,false);
```

Now add delay to the next stations (assuming that next stations have and id grather than current station)

```
myStations.stream()
                .filter(s -> s.getId()>current.getId())
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .forEach(s -> delay(s,minutes,true));
```

delay method (this delay method is based on java.time api)

```
public static void delay(Station current, int minutes, boolean isDelay){
    System.out.println("Current Station | Before: " + current);
    LocalDateTime stationArrival =null;
    LocalDateTime stationDeparture=null;


    if (current !=null && isDelay){
        stationArrival = getLocalDateTimeFromDate(current.getArrivalDate());
        stationDeparture = getLocalDateTimeFromDate(current.getDepartureDate());
        stationArrival=stationArrival.plusMinutes(minutes);
        stationDeparture=stationDeparture.plusMinutes(minutes);
        current.setArrivalDate(getDateFromLocalDateTime(stationArrival));
        current.setDepartureDate(getDateFromLocalDateTime(stationDeparture));
    }else if(current!=null && !isDelay){
        stationDeparture = getLocalDateTimeFromDate(current.getDepartureDate());
        stationDeparture= stationDeparture.plusMinutes(minutes);
        current.setDepartureDate(getDateFromLocalDateTime(stationDeparture));
    }

    System.out.println("Current Station | After: " + current);
}
```

helppers method to transform from Date <-> LocaleDateTime

```
public static  LocalDateTime getLocalDateTimeFromDate(Date date){
    return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
}

public static Date getDateFromLocalDateTime(LocalDateTime localDateTime){
    return Date.from(localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
}
```

This alternative is based on java.time api using LocalDateTime, java.time works perfect for me.  With java.uitl.Date there are many transformations to do, it is very hard to handle.  If you are interested to see more about java.time here is a tutorial [Java Date Time Api.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaDateTimeAPI/article.html)

Hope it helps.